# Android Studio showing me false error messages - MPAndroidChart Library

Tags: android, android-studio, mpandroidchart

Android Studio is constantly showing me wrong error messages, even though I can compile and run the source code correctly.

I'm using MPAndroidChart 3.0.2

Here are examples:

First, the value formatter.
It works properly, but it is shown as an error.

[image]

Second: Once again Android Studio is showing me an error message on this `LineData` parameter.

[image]

Last, but not least, `.setMode` on Dataset could not be found by Android Studio, but it runs perfectly.

Comment: Its better to embed your pictures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click on Invalidate caches/ Restart.  Check your imports to use the correct package name.